# Internet Explorer treating div width as 100%?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The width of the image (logo) appears to be 100% as it is pushing the divs underneath (header_box) down. All other browsers the header_boxes appear to the right of the logo, but Internet Explorer (of course) is doing something different.

html

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        <div class="header_box">
            <img id="profile" src="images/questionmark.png" alt="Profile Image" />
            <span id="profile_name">Sample</span><br />
            <ul id="profile_settings">
                <li>Profile</li>
                <li>Settings</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="header_box">
            <img id="notifications" src="images/notifications.png" alt="Notifications" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
background:#3A3A3A;
color:white;
border-bottom:5px #771439 solid;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 3px#888;
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 3px #888;
}

#logo {
height:82px;
display:inline;
}

.header_box {
display:inline-block;
float:right;
background:#262626;
padding:5px;
margin:16px 15px 12px 0;
border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
border: 1px #474747 solid;
text-align:left;
font-size:11px;
min-height:40px;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more info. I'm not really sure how to describe this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue in older versions of IE. You should be able to encase everything in a div with a height on it and include `float:left` in your logo css. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s6fbG/) is a jsfiddle to try it out.

HTML

```
<div style="height"82px;">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    <div class="header_box">
        <img id="profile" src="images/questionmark.png" alt="Profile Image" />
        <span id="profile_name">Sample</span><br />
        <ul id="profile_settings">
            <li>Profile</li>
            <li>Settings</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header_box">
        <img id="notifications" src="images/notifications.png" alt="Notifications" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {
float:left;
height:82px;
display:inline;
}
```